# Differentiable at every point in normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces, continuity

How can I prove that if $V$ and $W$ is normed vector spaces and $T \in LC(V; W)$, $T$ is differentiable at every point? And how to find its derivative? I have no idea how to start and what theorem to use to show that.

Comment: I assume that "LC" are linear, continuous maps. Just write down the definition of differentiability.

Comment: $(T(x+h)-T(x)-T(h)) / \|h\| =0$ for all $x$ for all $ h \neq 0$. What does this tell you?

Comment: You need to define what "differentiating" mean in that context.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but if $T$ is linear, $T(x+h)=T(x)+T(h)$. So, $(T(x+h)−T(x)−T(h))/∥h∥=0$ shows that it is differentiable at every point?

Comment: Yes. $T$ is differentiable at any point $x$ the derivative is $T$ itself.